# index out of range without if else statement python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I get the error "index out of range" with this function:

```
def encode(x):
     diff_char = x[0]
     max_ind = len(x)
     i = 1
     while i < max_ind and diff_char == x[i]:
         i += 1
     return str(i) + diff_char + encode(x[i:])
```

and why can I go through putting an if-else statement like this?

```
def encode(x):
    if not x:
        return ""
    else:
        diff_char = x[0]
        max_ind = len(x)
        i = 1
        while i < max_ind and diff_char == x[i]:
            i += 1
        return str(i) + diff_char + encode(x[i:])
```

Comment: `x[0]` triggers the out of range when `x` is empty, that's why.

Comment: What do you expect `x[0]` to do when `x` is empty?

Comment: Check first length of x should not be zero, i.e., if len(x) != 0.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is empty, i.e. `x = ''`, then accessing the index 0 will fail:

```
>>> x = ''
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is simply because the string has no first character at the index 0.

By checking for the truthiness of `x` first, you explicitly handle the case where `x` is the empty string. So in that case, you just return from the function and `x[0]` never attempts to read the first character.

Comment: Thanx mate. but what if I know that x is never going to be empty. Why should I check it anyway ?

Comment: @Juanloz if it's coming from user input or from input that somehow isn't what you're expecting - why wouldn't you check to prevent your program blowing up?

Comment: @Juanloz also... you should try and avoid recursion here as it's not necessary.... A non-empty input can break things as well... try: `encode('abc' * 1000)` for instance

Comment: Considering that you got the error before adding a check, I guess it’s safe to say that you are not guaranteeing properly that it’s not empty.

Comment: I agree with you guys. Better if I check if it's empty or not. But I just wanted to know why it does not work when the parameter is not empty. I'm just learning to use recursion. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `str(i) + diff_char + encode(x[i:])` in this case value of "i" is equal to your length of list x and and again you are calling your function recursively and in this case if length of x is 2  then i will be 2 here and x[2:] will give you blank list and when you call encode function then your accessing x[0] but your x is empty list.